# Can't work out this conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

For some positive $\lambda$ and probability measure defined by $\Pr\left((a,b]\right)=e^{-\lambda a}-e^{-\lambda b}$. We are working with $\Omega=(0,\infty)$ and the $\sigma$-algebra is borel of the same. I am trying to work out $\mathrm{E}\left[X\mid\sigma(Y)\right]$ and $\mathrm{E}\left[e^{-\alpha X}\mid\sigma(Y)\right]$ for $X$ and $Y$ defined as:

$X(\omega)=\omega$,

$Y(\omega)=\min\left\{\omega,\kappa\right\}$,

$\kappa$ is some positive constant.

I haven't made any progress. Any hints as to how I should go about this?

Comment: I suspect that $\Omega=(0,\infty)$ or $\Omega=[0,\infty)$ here (you are dealing with exponential distribution). If so then it should be added to the info in your question. If not then you must at least clarify: what is the meaning of $\min$ on $\Omega$?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: This looks like a very technical way of asking for the expected value of an exponential random variable $X$ (and of $e^{-\alpha X}$) given that $X>\kappa$.

Comment: How exactly would you justify that? It isn't as clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- For $y=\kappa$ we have: $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y=\kappa\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid X\geq\kappa\right]=\kappa+\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

The RHS is based on the fact that under condition $X\geq\kappa$ random variable $X-\kappa$ again has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. That rests on the fact that exponential distributions are [memoryless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness).

- For $y\in\left(0,\kappa\right)$ we have: $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y=y\right]=y$.

The two bullets together allow the conclusion that: $$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]=Y+\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{1}_{Y=\kappa}$$

Try to find $\mathbb E[e^{-\alpha X}\mid Y]$ on a similar way.